# How multiple CASE WHEN scenario works in SQL?

Tags: sql, case

If in a query we have 2 case scenario satisfying the condition, which one will be picked by the SQL to show the output ?

sample Query :

```
    SELECT 
         CASE 
             WHEN field1 = 'a' THEN 1
             WHEN field2 = 'a' THEN 2
             ELSE 3
         END
    from table ;
```

Comment: The case is evaluated from left to right.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter in this case, but best to tag _which_ implementation of SQL you use.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL they will be evaluated in the order they are written so the first match wins.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a condition is true within your case conditions it will ignore all the later conditions.

If field1='a' then it will return 1 even if field2='a'. But if field1<>'a' and field2='a' then it will return 2 and only if field1 and field2 are both not 'a' then it will return 3.

I am assuming that field1 and field2 are column names.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please let us know if you are facing any other difficulties. Best wishes.